# Getting Invalid JSON error in Dev console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parse-platform, back4app

I'm making a react app and want to connect it to my Back4App database.
I have a Person class in the Back4App dashboard with data that should be returned, it seems like the call is being made but I am getting an error in the dev console. I am initializing Parse correctly so I don't think it's an issue with that. Any help very much appreciated!

Error that I'm getting:
[Dev console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWw1T.png)

Code for call:

```html
export async function fetchUser() {
    // create your Parse Query using the Person Class you've created
    const query = new Parse.Query('Person');
    // use the equalTo filter to look for user which the name is John
    query.equalTo('name', 'Jakob');
    // run the query
    const user = await query.first();

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your request is going to localhost.  I assume that should be something like: `https://parseapi.back4app.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error says that

```
http://localhost:3000/classes/Person
```

is not found, are you sure this is the correct route? because it can't be found